# Add gain to AVAudiosession iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm trying to add more gain to the AVAudioSession.

I'm using AVAssetWriter to record a video with audio, but I would like to add more gain to the audio.

I saw there is a method in AVAudioSession to set the `inputGain`, but it must be between 0 and 1.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setInputGain:2.0 error:nil];
```

Is there any way to add more gain even if I have to lose quality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got this using Audiounit framework

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the gain yourself by modifying the incoming audio LPCM  `CMSampleBuffer`s before you pass them on to the `AVAssetWriter`. NB: `AVCaptureSession` may not take kindly to you modifying its buffers, so you may need to duplicate them *before* modifying.

Alternatively, you may get more gain using `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement`:

```
NSError *error;
if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&error]) {
    // Error
}
```

which is

> Appropriate for applications that wish to minimize the effect of system-supplied signal
>   processing for input and/or output audio signals.

Comment: I'm loosing gain using AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement. Do I have to do it in different way? Do You have some example for modify CMSampleBuffer?